# char array on stack causes seg fault

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

This might be expected but I'm just curious as to how/why this happens.

When i try to use a `char *` declared locally `char * foo = "\xFF\xFF..."` as an integer it seg faults. But if I use malloc it works perfectly well when i try to access it. Why does this happen?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned char *buf = malloc(16);
  memcpy(buf, "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF", 16);
  //unsigned char *buf = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"; // seg faults if you sue this instead

  uint64_t *k  = (uint64_t *) buf;
  uint64_t *k2 = (uint64_t *) (buf + 8);
  uint64_t i  = 1000000000;

  printf("-k =%" PRIu64 "\n", *k);
  printf("-k2=%" PRIu64 "\n", *k2);

  printf("Iter * %" PRIu64  "\n", i);
  for (uint64_t c = 0; c < i; ++c)
    {
      *k  += 1;
      *k2 -= 1;
    }

  printf("-k =%" PRIu64 "\n", *k);
  printf("-k2=%" PRIu64 "\n", *k2);

  return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
easytiger $ gcc -std=c99 tar.c -Wall -O2 ; time ./a.out
-k =0
-k2=18446744073709551615
Iter * 1000000000
-k =1000000000
-k2=18446744072709551615
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do....?!?! And why is your C question tagged [tag:c++]?

Comment: Even if the string literal were writable (which it is not), the code may fail on certain architectures because of alignment.

Comment: A mistake. And I was just seeing what would happen. It isn't for any code i'm writing.

Comment: Just use `unsigned char buf[] = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";` ... no need to `malloc()` these few bytes if they're only needed locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals are immutable. You may not modify the data stored there. Ever.

Even in C nowadays we make this clear and diagnosable by lobbing a `const` into the pointer type.

C++ actually requires it.

Comment: +1 for this, which when combined with your comment to dbush below, is the most thorough and nuanced answer here, rather than oversimplifying.

Comment: I think this answer gives a more accurate overview of the mechanism behind this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go (namely .rodata)

Comment: @easytiger: I was very deliberate in _not_ talking about implementation details / mechanism of some specific compiler. This question is about C, a high-level programming language that abstracts away such details by definition. When you start obsessing over implementation details like that answer does, you make assumptions and sweeping statements that cannot be guaranteed to hold, particularly in the face of so-called "optimisations" (where "optimisations" just means "the compiler doing its job in an optimal manner that the author failed to consider"). :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that string literals will be stored in a writable memory page. This means that the `*k += 1` operations in the for loop will likely try to write to read-only memory.  Memory allocated by `malloc`, on the other hand, will always be writable.

Answer (score 3):

For a definition of this form:

```
unsigned char *buf = "some string";
```

`buf` points to a static string which is stored in a read-only portion of memory.  When you try to write to it, you get a segfault.

By using `malloc`, the memory pointed to by `buf` is writeable.

Comment: It may not be stored in read-only memory. And whether it is or not doesn't even really matter: the language prohibits you from mutating a string literal's constituent characters, if you want your program to have well-defined semantics. Rationalising about it beyond that is pointless.

Comment: Thanks, it's that simple then.  Lightness Races in Orbit makes a good point too. I guess the malloc version is not treated at all like a string literal.

Comment: Because it _isn't_ a literal. (The fact that it is `memcpy`d from one is not relevant.)

Comment: Yepper. You can even start talking about the odds of the literal being optimised away and whatever and blah blah blah but there's no need. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The language doesn't prohibit it but declares it "undefined behavior". That's why the code compiles -- the reason it segfaults at runtime is technically INDEED that it is placed in read-only memory. This of course is ok because a program could do ANYTHING on UB.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I was careful with my words, and you should be careful with reading them. I said the language prohibits doing this "if you want your program to have well-defined semantics". I'm just bored of saying "it's UB" over and over again ;)

Comment: Well, that's nitpicking of course, but talking about semantics, I'd expect prohibitions to be enforced ;)

Comment: Undefined behaviour != a prohibition. That's why it has its own term. Note LRiO used "prohibit" informally, with the qualifier _if_ you want well-defined results. You can still do it, but don't expect predictable behaviour across compilers. In many cases, compilers don't strictly protect against UB because accommodating a tonne of edge cases would be an inefficient use of dev time, user compile time, and possibly runtime.